# iOS MFI controller connection issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, mfi

i have this code that is a Plugin for Unreal Engine 4 is to allow MFI game controllers (Physical Bluetooth Gamepad, Joystick) to be used in my game on iOS devices

the plugin works fine if the game (App) is launched before connecting the controller

the problem is if the game controller is connected before launching the game the game crashes after the splash screen
also disconnecting the controller whilst the game is running closes/crashes the game

any advice is much appreciated

```
#include "IOSInputInterfacePrivatePCH.h"
#include "IInputInterface.h"
#include "IOSGamepad.h"


/** Beginning of FGCControllerNotificationHandler class */
#if PLATFORM_IOS
@interface FGCControllerNotificationHandler : NSObject

@property FIOSGamepad* device;

+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation FGCControllerNotificationHandler

@synthesize device;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

+ (id)alloc
{
    return [super allocWithZone:NULL];
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [[self sharedInstance] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount {
    return NSUIntegerMax; /** denotes an object that cannot be released */
}

- (oneway void)release {
    /** never release */
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (FGCControllerNotificationHandler *)sharedInstance
{
    static FGCControllerNotificationHandler* instance;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (instance == nil)
        {
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

- (void)registerObservers:(FIOSGamepad *)inDevice
{
    self.device = inDevice;

    NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    /** Assign controller when connected */
    [center addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(setupControllers)
                    name:GCControllerDidConnectNotification
                  object:nil];

    /** Do something after controller disconnection */
    [center addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(cleanControllers)
                    name:GCControllerDidDisconnectNotification
                  object:nil];

    /** Search for another controller */
    [GCController startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler:nil];

    /** Assign controller id for known controllers */
    if ([[GCController controllers] count] > 0)
    {
        [self setupControllers];
    }
}

- (void)setupControllers
{
    if(device != nil)
    {
        self.device->OnControllerConnected();
    }
}

- (void)cleanControllers
{
    if(device != nil)
    {
        self.device->OnControllerDisconnected();
    }
}

- (int32)getControllerCount
{
    return (int32)[[GCController controllers] count];
}

- (TArray<GCController *>)getConnectedControllers
{
    TArray<GCController *> availableControllers;
    for (GCController* c in [GCController controllers])
    {
        availableControllers.Add(c);
    }
    return availableControllers;
}

@end
#endif
/** End of FGCControllerNotificationHandler class */


/** Beginning of FIOSGamepad class */
FIOSGamepad::FIOSGamepad(const TSharedRef<FGenericApplicationMessageHandler>& InMessageHandler) :
    MessageHandler(InMessageHandler)
{
#if PLATFORM_IOS
    /** In the engine, all controllers map to xbox controllers for consistency */
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[0] = 0;      // FaceButtonBottom
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[1] = 1;      // FaceButtonRight
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[2] = 2;      // FaceButtonLeft
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[3] = 3;      // FaceButtonTop
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[4] = 4;      // L1
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[5] = 5;      // R1
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[6] = 6;      // None
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[7] = 7;      // None
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[8] = 8;      // None
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[9] = 9;      // None
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[10] = 10;    // L2
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[11] = 11;    // R2
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[12] = 12;    // Dpad up
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[13] = 13;    // Dpad down
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[14] = 14;    // Dpad left
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[15] = 15;    // Dpad right
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[16] = 16;    // Left stick up
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[17] = 17;    // Left stick down
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[18] = 18;    // Left stick left
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[19] = 19;    // Left stick right
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[20] = 20;    // Right stick up
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[21] = 21;    // Right stick down
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[22] = 22;    // Right stick left
    IOSToXboxControllerMapping[23] = 23;    // Right stick right

    Buttons[0] = FGamepadKeyNames::FaceButtonBottom;
    Buttons[1] = FGamepadKeyNames::FaceButtonRight;
    Buttons[2] = FGamepadKeyNames::FaceButtonLeft;
    Buttons[3] = FGamepadKeyNames::FaceButtonTop;
    Buttons[4] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftShoulder;
    Buttons[5] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightShoulder;
    Buttons[6] = FGamepadKeyNames::SpecialRight;
    Buttons[7] = FGamepadKeyNames::SpecialLeft;
    Buttons[8] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftThumb;
    Buttons[9] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightThumb;
    Buttons[10] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftTriggerThreshold;
    Buttons[11] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightTriggerThreshold;
    Buttons[12] = FGamepadKeyNames::DPadUp;
    Buttons[13] = FGamepadKeyNames::DPadDown;
    Buttons[14] = FGamepadKeyNames::DPadLeft;
    Buttons[15] = FGamepadKeyNames::DPadRight;
    Buttons[16] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftStickUp;
    Buttons[17] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftStickDown;
    Buttons[18] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftStickLeft;
    Buttons[19] = FGamepadKeyNames::LeftStickRight;
    Buttons[20] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightStickUp;
    Buttons[21] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightStickDown;
    Buttons[22] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightStickLeft;
    Buttons[23] = FGamepadKeyNames::RightStickRight;

    bNeedsControllerStateUpdate = true;
    InitialButtonRepeatDelay = 0.2f;
    ButtonRepeatDelay = 0.1f;

    /** Initialize ControllerStates */
    for (int32 ControllerIndex=0; ControllerIndex < MAX_NUM_IOS_CONTROLLERS; ++ControllerIndex)
    {
        FControllerState& ControllerState = ControllerStates[ControllerIndex];
        FMemory::Memzero(&ControllerState, sizeof(FControllerState));

        ControllerState.ControllerId = ControllerIndex;
    }

    [[FGCControllerNotificationHandler sharedInstance] registerObservers:this];
#endif
}

FIOSGamepad::~FIOSGamepad()
{
}

void FIOSGamepad::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
}

void FIOSGamepad::SendControllerEvents()
{
#if PLATFORM_IOS
    for (int32 ControllerIndex=0; ControllerIndex < MAX_NUM_IOS_CONTROLLERS; ++ControllerIndex)
    {
        FControllerState& ControllerState = ControllerStates[ControllerIndex];
        if (!ControllerState.bIsConnected && bNeedsControllerStateUpdate)
        {
            ControllerState.bIsConnected = (ControllerIndex < ((int32) [[GCController controllers] count]));
        }
        if (ControllerState.bIsConnected)
        {
            bool CurrentStates[MAX_NUM_IOS_CONTROLLER_BUTTONS] = {0};
            GCController* Controller = [GCController controllers][ControllerIndex];
            if (Controller.extendedGamepad != nil)
            {
                GCExtendedGamepad* ExGamepad = Controller.extendedGamepad;

                /** Check Analog state */
                if(ControllerState.LeftXAnalog != ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::LeftAnalogX, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value);
                    ControllerState.LeftXAnalog = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value;
                }

                if(ControllerState.LeftYAnalog != ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::LeftAnalogY, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value);
                    ControllerState.LeftYAnalog = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value;
                }

                if(ControllerState.RightXAnalog != ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::RightAnalogX, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value);
                    ControllerState.RightXAnalog = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value;
                }

                if(ControllerState.RightYAnalog != ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::RightAnalogY, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value);
                    ControllerState.RightYAnalog = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value;
                }

                if(ControllerState.LeftTriggerAnalog != ExGamepad.leftTrigger.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::LeftTriggerAnalog, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.leftTrigger.value);
                    ControllerState.LeftTriggerAnalog = ExGamepad.leftTrigger.value;
                }

                if(ControllerState.RightTriggerAnalog != ExGamepad.rightTrigger.value)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerAnalog(FGamepadKeyNames::RightTriggerAnalog, ControllerState.ControllerId, ExGamepad.rightTrigger.value);
                    ControllerState.RightTriggerAnalog = ExGamepad.rightTrigger.value;
                }

                /** Get the current state of all buttons */
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[0]] = ExGamepad.buttonA.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[1]] = ExGamepad.buttonB.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[2]] = ExGamepad.buttonX.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[3]] = ExGamepad.buttonY.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[4]] = ExGamepad.leftShoulder.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[5]] = ExGamepad.rightShoulder.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[6]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[7]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[8]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[9]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[10]] = ExGamepad.leftTrigger.value > IOS_TRIGGER_THRESHOLD;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[11]] = ExGamepad.rightTrigger.value > IOS_TRIGGER_THRESHOLD;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[12]] = ExGamepad.dpad.up.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[13]] = ExGamepad.dpad.down.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[14]] = ExGamepad.dpad.left.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[15]] = ExGamepad.dpad.right.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[16]] = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.up;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[17]] = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.down;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[18]] = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.left;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[19]] = ExGamepad.leftThumbstick.right;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[20]] = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.up;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[21]] = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.down;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[22]] = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.left;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[23]] = ExGamepad.rightThumbstick.right;
            }

            else if (Controller.gamepad != nil)
            {
                GCGamepad* Gamepad = Controller.gamepad;

                /** Get the current state of all buttons */
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[0]] = Gamepad.buttonA.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[1]] = Gamepad.buttonB.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[2]] = Gamepad.buttonX.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[3]] = Gamepad.buttonY.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[4]] = Gamepad.leftShoulder.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[5]] = Gamepad.rightShoulder.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[6]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[7]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[8]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[9]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[10]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[11]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[12]] = Gamepad.dpad.up.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[13]] = Gamepad.dpad.down.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[14]] = Gamepad.dpad.left.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[15]] = Gamepad.dpad.right.pressed;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[16]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[17]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[18]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[19]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[20]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[21]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[22]] = false;
                CurrentStates[IOSToXboxControllerMapping[23]] = false;
            }

            const double CurrentTime = FPlatformTime::Seconds();

            /** For each button check against the previous state and send the correct message if any */
            for (int32 ButtonIndex = 0; ButtonIndex < MAX_NUM_IOS_CONTROLLER_BUTTONS; ++ButtonIndex)
            {
                if(CurrentStates[ButtonIndex] != ControllerState.ButtonStates[ButtonIndex])
                {
                    if(CurrentStates[ButtonIndex])
                    {
                        MessageHandler->OnControllerButtonPressed(Buttons[ButtonIndex], ControllerState.ControllerId, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageHandler->OnControllerButtonReleased(Buttons[ButtonIndex], ControllerState.ControllerId, false);
                    }

                    if(CurrentStates[ButtonIndex] == true)
                    {
                        /** this button was pressed - set the button's NextRepeatTime to the InitialButtonRepeatDelay */
                        ControllerState.NextRepeatTime[ButtonIndex] = CurrentTime + InitialButtonRepeatDelay;
                    }
                }

                else if(CurrentStates[ButtonIndex] == true && ControllerState.NextRepeatTime[ButtonIndex] <= CurrentTime)
                {
                    MessageHandler->OnControllerButtonPressed(Buttons[ButtonIndex], ControllerState.ControllerId, true);

                    /** set the button's NextRepeatTime to the ButtonRepeatDelay */
                    ControllerState.NextRepeatTime[ButtonIndex] = CurrentTime + ButtonRepeatDelay;
                }

                /** Update the state for next time */
                ControllerState.ButtonStates[ButtonIndex] = CurrentStates[ButtonIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    bNeedsControllerStateUpdate = false;
#endif
}

void FIOSGamepad::SetMessageHandler(const TSharedRef<FGenericApplicationMessageHandler>&InMessageHandler)
{
    MessageHandler = InMessageHandler;
}

bool FIOSGamepad::Exec(UWorld* InWorld, const TCHAR* Cmd, FOutputDevice& Ar)
{
    return false;
}

void FIOSGamepad::SetChannelValue (int32 ControllerId, FForceFeedbackChannelType ChannelType, float Value)
{
}

void FIOSGamepad::SetChannelValues (int32 ControllerId, const FForceFeedbackValues &values)
{
}

void FIOSGamepad::OnControllerConnected ()
{
    for(int32 ControllerIndex=0; ControllerIndex < FMath::Min<int32>(MAX_NUM_IOS_CONTROLLERS, [[GCController controllers] count]); ++ControllerIndex)
    {
        [GCController controllers][ControllerIndex].playerIndex = (GCControllerPlayerIndex)ControllerIndex;
    }

    this->bNeedsControllerStateUpdate = true;
}

void FIOSGamepad::OnControllerDisconnected ()
{
    this->bNeedsControllerStateUpdate = true;
}

/** End of FIOSGamepad class */
```

Comment: Do you get any crash logs in console?

Comment: yes when the controller is connected and the i run the App i get two crash logs

Comment: i couldn't figure how to display them here (to many characters) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1dXYRUVEd4NdGNJSmF4X3FtTDg

Comment: If you run it with XCode?

Comment: I can't run the app in Xcode, but I got the logs from the device when connected to Xcode.